# Не заполняется <li> с классом при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу чтобы программа определяла день недели и заполняла расписание в связи с этим, но она заполняет только div, а li не заполняет, что не так?

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>&#10084;</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="TODAY">
    </div>

    <ul class="items">
      <li class="todayfirst"></li>
      <li class="todaysecond"></li>
      <li class="todaythird"></li>
      <li class="todayother"></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="TOMORROW">
    </div>

    <ul class="items">
      <li class="tomorrowfirst"></li>
      <li class="tomorrowsecond"></li>
      <li class="tomorrowthird"></li>
      <li class="tomorrowother"></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
            var mn = "Понедельник";
            var tu = "Вторник";
            var wd = "Среда";
            var th = "Четверг";
            var fr = "Пятница";
            var st = "Суббота";
            var sd = "Воскресенье";

            var mn1 = "Линейная алгебра в 9:30-10:50 230 аудитория";
            var mn2 = "Программирование 11:10-12:30 402 аудитория";

            var tu1 = "Дискретная математика в 9:30-10:50 224 аудитория";
            var tu2 = "Программирование 11:10-12:30 146 аудитория";
            var tu3 = "Дискретная математика в 12:40-14:00 206 аудитория";

            var wd1 = "Алгебра в 11:10-12:30 319 аудитория";

            var th1 = "Английский язык в 11:10-12:30 203 аудитория";
            var th2 = "Английский язык в 12:40-14:00 203 аудитория";

            var fr1 = "Психология(лекция) в 11:10-12:30 225 аудитория";
            var fr2 = "Психология(практика) в 12:40-14:00 206 аудитория";

            var st1 = "Мат.Анализ(лекция) в 9:30-10:50 302 аудитория";
            var st2 = "Мат.Анализ(практика) в 11:10-12:30 302 аудитория";

            var sd1 = "Можно почилить &#10084";

            var DAYNUMBER = new Date().getDay();
            var today = document.getElementById('TODAY');
            var tomorrow = document.getElementById('TOMORROW');
            var todayfirst = document.getElementsByClassName('todayfirst');
            var todaysecond = document.getElementsByClassName('todaysecond');
            var todaythird = document.getElementsByClassName('todaythird');
            var todayother = document.getElementsByClassName('todayother');
            var tomorrowfirst = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrowfirst');
            var tomorrowsecond = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrowsecond');
            var tomorrowthird = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrowthird');
            var tomorrowother = document.getElementsByClassName('tomorrowother');
            switch(DAYNUMBER){
              case 1: today.innerHTML=mn;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=mn1;
                      todaysecond.innerHTML=mn2;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=tu;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=tu1;
                      tomorrowsecond.innerHTML=tu2;
                      tomorrowthird.innerHTML=tu3;

              break;
              case 2: today.innerHTML=tu;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=tu1;
                      todaysecond.innerHTML=tu2;
                      todaythird.innerHTML=tu3;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=wd;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=wd1;
              break;
              case 3: today.innerHTML=wd;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=wd1;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=th;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=th1;
                      tomorrowsecond.innerHTML=th2;
              break;
              case 4: today.innerHTML=th;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=th1;
                      todaysecond.innerHTML=th2;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=fr;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=fr1;
                      tomorrowsecond.innerHTML=fr2;
                      tomorrowother.innerHTML="На лекции будет тест!!!";

              break;
              case 5: today.innerHTML=fr;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=fr1;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=fr2;
                      todayother.innerHTML="На лекции будет тест!!!";

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=st;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=st1;
                      tomorrowsecond.innerHTML=st2;
              break;
              case 6: today.innerHTML=st;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=st1;
                      todaysecond.innerHTML=st2;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=sd;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=sd1;
              break;
              case 7: today.innerHTML=sd;
                      todayfirst.innerHTML=sd1;

                      tomorrow.innerHTML=md;
                      tomorrowfirst.innerHTML=mn1;
                      tomorrowsecond.innerHTML=mn2;

              break;
            }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: объекты и массивы порой облегчают жизнь

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб вывести новое значение, надо получить сам элемент, а вы получаете массивоподобный объект.
Вот так будет работать:

```
var todayfirst = document.getElementsByClassName('todayfirst')[0];
todayfirst.innerHTML = "test"
```